# Escape key is closing a Windows Forms form with no code or settings tied to it

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am using VB.NET in Visual Studio 2010 targeting .NET Framework 3.5.

In our (rather large) client application, there's one form ([Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms)) we're having an issue with. It's displayed with .ShowDialog (it's not the only form displayed with .ShowDialog). There are Close and Cancel buttons on the form, and the Enter key and Escape key, respectively, are tied to these controls (and that's also done on other forms). The code in the buttons performs a Hide method call to make the form not visible (it's actually unloaded later in the business process logic), and again we do this elsewhere with other forms.

Clicking the Close or Cancel buttons works as desired. Pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key also works as desired (Close click is run). But when the Escape key is pressed, first the Cancel button logic is run, as expected, but then we receive a Form Closed event, and the form is unloaded!

There is no code elsewhere looking for the Escape key and performing an Close on the form. We tried to set the Cancel argument in the Closing event, but to no avail - the form still unloads. We also disconnected the Escape key from the Cancel button, pressing Escape then doesn't run the Cancel code (as then expected), but the Form Closed event still fires.

I haven't been able to replicate this behavior in a test program, so unfortunately I can't post a working (non-working, actually) code example.

Any input as to what's going on? Why is the Escape key closing the form?

Perhaps most importantly, what do I need to do to investigate this further and figure it out?

Comment: I suppose you have the property CancelButton on the form set to the Cancel button.

Comment: Code would help.  Show us the code that creates and shows the form, as well as any other code that interacts with the form object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first suspect is `CancelButton` of the form. Also check the `DialogResult` of the cancel button.

If you set the `CancelButton` of the form to a button, pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key calls the button's `Click` event, sets the form's `DialogResult` to `Cancel` and closes the form. Also when you set the [`DialogResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.dialogresult.aspx) property of a button to anything other than `None`, clicking the button will close the form. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.dialogresult.aspx):

> If the DialogResult for this property is set to anything other than None, and if the parent form was displayed through the ShowDialog method, clicking the button closes the parent form without your having to hook up any events.

To investigate further, override `OnFormClosing` method on the form, set a break-point on the method, and when the break-point is hit, give us the current call-stack (from the Call Stack window).

Comment: It is DialogResult that's the issue, it needs to be set back to None to prevent the form from closing.

Comment: I shall investigate the DialogResult button property, though this will probably take me a few days to get into it in detail.  Thank you for the suggestions and info.

Comment: DialogResult for my Close and Cancel buttons was None, so running those didn't set the form DialogResult property.  Pressing the Esc key did set the form DialogResult to Cancel, per MD Unicorn's comment above.  I am now resetting the form DialogResult to None in the form OnFormClosing override and I'm no longer seeing the form close. Thanks!